# Heroku postgres ingress - could not connect to server error

Tags: php, heroku, heroku-postgres, php-pgsql

**Background..**
I'm trying to connect to my heroku database externally from a php script and I'm getting a "Could not connect to server" error

**The tech..**
It's a "crane" production level database, not a shared database. 
I'm trying to connect from a php script, running on a shared hosting platform,

**The story so far..** 
I can connect from my local machine and php connection strings that postgres.heroku.com outputs. I can also connect with the psql string so there's nothing wrong with the connection info

.. but when I move that php script to a php server that I have up and running on another host, then i get a "could not connect" error.. Those hosts assure me that there are no restrictions on making external connections from their side.

**The code..**

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=ec2-54-235-162-154.compute-1.amazonaws.com port=5882 dbname=***** user=***** password=***** sslmode=require options='--client_encoding=UTF8'") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
```

**The error..**

```
Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "ec2-54-235-162-154.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5882? in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/164125/webspace/httpdocs/scheduled/postgres_vr.php on line 3 Warning: pg_last_error(): No PostgreSQL link opened yet in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/164125/webspace/httpdocs/scheduled/postgres_vr.php on line 3 Could not connect:
```

**Options**

I can't find any documentation in heroku about whitelisting an IP address which would be first guess? Any other pointers?

**EDIT** I just found this thread, which is similar ..
[Heroku Postgres Connection from localhost PHP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393269/heroku-postgres-connection-from-localhost-php-application) .. but I have the correct ssl settings enabled as far as I can see.
Here's the relevant section from the phpinfo() on the openssl and pgsql respectively..

```
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008

PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   8.1.23
Multibyte character support enabled
SSL support enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pgsql.allow_persistent  On  On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent Off Off
pgsql.ignore_notice Off Off
pgsql.log_notice    Off Off
pgsql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
pgsql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
```

Comment: can you confirm your php was compiled `--with-openssl`? you can check via a page with `phpinfo();` Look for 
`OpenSSL support`

Comment: Yep, it's enabled alright. OpenSSL/0.9.8b

Comment: There is no IP whitelisting. Can you connect with `$ heroku pg:psql -a app_name` (using the Heroku Toolbelt)?

Comment: Yep, that command works locally.

Comment: Since this works locally with `psql`, I'm removing the Heroku tag, we've effectively ruled Heroku out as the issue.

Answer (score 0):

this works locally, but not on a separate server.  The error says it cannot make the connection suggesting it never completes the syn/ack handshake.  Since this works from your computer we can eliminate both Heroku and PostgreSQL.  The specific error and scenario suggest it is not PHP.

So it has to be something else.  The first thing I would look at are any firewalls that sit between your server and the internet.  Failing that, check any settings you may have on the AWS EC instance particularly regarding iptables.